# Ionic framework get Location and http request

Tags: angularjs, promise, ionic-framework

I'm trying to get current user coordinates and afterwards send them as a parameter of http request and parse response.
Workflow is next -> user opens view, (loader shown) - coordinates are retrieved (if not send request without coordinates) - send requests - parse and display response - hide loader.

What is the best way to achieve this?
I have tried to create two services, to retrieve coordinates using navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition, but I'm unable to return promise in which i would send http request using $http.get.

This workflow should be used in different controllers so I'm searching for a way which code will be most reusable. Thanks!

Update: this is a code sample of how I did resolve waiting for $http to complete before view is shown, but I have no idea how to use same approach with navigator.geolocation as it is not returning a promise.

```
.state('tab.explore.index', {
                url: '',
                templateUrl: 'templates/tab-explore.html',
                controller: 'ExploreCtrl',
                resolve: {
                    explore: function ($stateParams, Explore) {
                        console.log("rr");
                        return Explore.explore();
                    }
                }
  });
```

Service:

```
.factory('Explore', ["$http", "ApiEndPoint", "Resort", "ServiceTypes", function ($http, ApiEndPoint, Resort) {

        return {
            explore: function () {
                console.log("loc");
                 **//somehow somewhere here should code wait to retrieve coordinates and send them as url parameter**
                var url = ApiEndPoint().explore + Resort.id;
                return $http.get(url);
            }
        }
    }]);
```

controler:

```
.controller('ExploreCtrl',function ($scope, $stateParams,ServiceTypes,explore) {
       console.log(explore.data.Services);
                $scope.serviceTypes = ServiceTypes;
                $scope.explore = explore.data;
})
```

Comment: Can you show us your current attempt?

Comment: Well actually no, because i have no idea how I can return promise from navigator.geolocation. I will update question with my code how I've resolved waiting for $http.get to complete, but I'm out of ideas for navigator. 
My last resort is to call both calls into controller and nest callbacks but this is worst solution as code is not reuseable at all